# A way to gather stock images of a particular size on iOS

Tags: images, ios, search

I find very often I need to put in some photos to some web app, like a freelance gig or some profile or activity.

It’s very common after gathering some from google images you find out many of them are the wrong size or dimensions.

I was wondering what is a good fix for this. You can just search google images for images of the right dimensions. But maybe there is some more convenient way to try to get some pictures where you don’t have to worry that the dimensions may be wrong? Some app that provides tons of stock photos from the internet, but offers better search functionality, maybe? Or easier filetype conversation or resizing? Or just like a dedicated, stand-alone app for searching for online photos, like google images but somehow a bit more cushioned, feature-ful, convenient?